# display time according to the time zone the file was created

Tags: python

Windows ( Alt-Enter ) on the file returns the actual time, but the python function returns GMT. Is there anyway to know the timezone from os.stat(), in order to calculate the actual time? I hope my question is clear

This is my function -

```
# get seconds since epoch
test_time_since_epoch = os.stat(value[0]).st_mtime

time_format = "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"
test_time_formatted = time.strftime(time_format, time.gmtime(test_time_since_epoch))
```

The function for example returns DD MM YY 10:00:00, but the actual time of the file is DD MM YY 12:00:00

Comment: *Windows ( Alt-Enter ) on the file returns the actual time* not for me.

Comment: Timezone information is not part of file creation. Windows is likely just taking its own configured timezone. Do you want to display the time according to your current timezone?

Comment: @DirtyBit - I just created a text file and did Alt Enter. It shows the time in my timezone ( actual time ) and not GMT. Can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi : yes, using python modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(test_time_since_epoch).strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp

> Return the local date corresponding to the POSIX timestamp....

Comment: `gmtime` converts the time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a struct_time in UTC. And `strftime` converts the format so you are not getting the local time but UTC time. `fromtimestamp` on the other hand gets the local time.

Comment: And this cannot be acheived by the time module? Just wanted to omit extra dependancies in the code, even though datetime is a part of standard package.

Comment: @infoclogged https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime

Comment: @Goyo : feel free to write an answer if you want. If it works, then yours is closer to my query.